# Magento sending blank token in paypal express checkout

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.2. I tried to use the paypal express checkout , every time I try to place order for first time, It is showing the error, "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token). ", when I logged the data to see the parameter it is sending blank token and blank payerID

```
    2012-12-19T10:06:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
    (
[url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
[DoExpressCheckoutPayment] => Array
    (
        [TOKEN] => 
        [PAYERID] => 
        [PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
        [AMT] => 7.14
        [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => Varien_Cart_EC_US
        [NOTIFYURL] => http://www.samit.com/hungermunch/chinagardenstore/paypal/ipn/
        [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
        [ITEMAMT] => 6.84
        [TAXAMT] => 0.30
        [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
        [L_NUMBER0] => Fullmenu-001
        [L_NAME0] => Chicken Salad (For 2 Persons)
        [L_QTY0] => 1
        [L_AMT0] => 5.95
        [L_NUMBER1] => tips/gratiuty
        [L_NAME1] => Tips/Gratuity
        [L_QTY1] => 1
        [L_AMT1] => 0.89
        [BUSINESS] => 
        [EMAIL] => rimalsamit@yahoo.com
        [FIRSTNAME] => Samit
        [LASTNAME] => Rimal
        [MIDDLENAME] => 
        [SALUTATION] => 
        [SUFFIX] => 
        [COUNTRYCODE] => US
        [STATE] => CA
        [CITY] => San Jose
        [STREET] => 1 Main St
        [ZIP] => 95131
        [PHONENUM] => 9841669912
        [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
        [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
        [SHIPTOCITY] => San Jose
        [SHIPTOSTREET] => 1 Main St
        [SHIPTOZIP] => 95131
        [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 9841669912
        [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
        [STREET2] => 
        [SHIPTONAME] => Samit Rimal
        [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
        [METHOD] => DoExpressCheckoutPayment
        [VERSION] => 72.0
        [USER] => ****
        [PWD] => ****
        [SIGNATURE] => ****
    )

[response] => Array
    (
        [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-12-19T10:06:26Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => 949b5ccdc7293
        [ACK] => Failure
        [VERSION] => 72.0
        [BUILD] => 4181146
        [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10410
        [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid token
        [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Invalid token.
        [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    )

[__pid] => 3828
```

)
When I tried to place order for second time,  I found that there was a token in request,So is it possible to to set token manually in the start of the express checkout ? Or  any solution for it?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.